# Algum dialeto do português brasileiro usa "nem" onde normalmente se usa "não"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, diferenças, regionalismo, concordância-negativa

Eu tenho uma amiga mineira.  Notei que ela fala frequentemente a palavra "nem" aonde eu esperaria a palavra "não".  Eu não sei se isso é certo, mas me acostumei a só ouvir "nem" quando se nega uma coisa, e depois uma outra coisa também (like how "neither" and "nor" work in English), por exemplo "eu não faço isso nem isso".  Talvez tenha situações além disso aonde é certinho usar "nem", que eu até não entendi, mas por fato que eu ainda não notei nada estranho com o jeito de usar "nem" com todos os meus outros amigos brasileiros (que são de outras regiões), me faz pensar que isso é uma característica de um dialeto.

Também, conheci umas paulistas velhinhas que falam "num" para não, então sei que isso é uma coisa que pode mudar regionalmente.

Por exemplo, ela usa "nem" quando tá concordando:

> "tô bem ocupado aqui, não tenho muito tempo pra sair"
>
> "nem tô saindo muito também".

Será que isso é bem normal, e eu não entendi como usar "nem" normalmente?.  Caso sim, há outros exemplos que são estranhos também.  Eu acho que às vezes ela usa nem no começo de falar, por exemplo:

> "oi tudo bem, tá ocupado agora?"
>
> "nem tô, vamo conversar"

Ou algo assim.

Sei com certeza que isso normalmente seria "não tô, vamos conversar", né?

Alguém aqui já ouviu pessoas falarem assim?

Como sempre, tentei escrever a minha pergunta no melhor jeito que eu consigo, mas com certeza errei muito.  Obrigado pela ajuda e a paciência de vocês.

---

To try and be clear here, in case my Portuguese is too bad to understand.

Is the use of "nem" instead of "não" in the 2 examples above a regional thing or a "standard BP" thing?

Are there any dialects where "nem" is used almost completely interchangeably with "não", (or at least much more commonly than in standard Portuguese), and does this apply to Minas Gerais?

Does the "nem" in these phrases hold any additional meaning than a simple "não" would? If so, what are the distinctions?

Comment: "nem tô lendo/saindo etc" este 'nem' denota uma falta de interesse, não gosta ou não quer fazer, não tem vontade de fazer, não sente falta de fazer, ou tem preguiça de fazer algo; "nem tô, vamos conversar" este 'nem' significa 'não'

Comment: é?  então, se eu falar "tô muito ocupado, não tô saindo", significa só que eu não saio, mas se eu falar "tô muito ocupado, nem tô saindo", significa que eu não saio nem quero sair?

Comment: se falasse "nem estou bebendo muito no momento", não poderia significa por exemplo que gostaria de fazer-lo só que fico sem grana XD ? Ou teria que falar "não estou bebendo muito no momento" pra dizer isso

Comment: "tô muito ocupado, nem tô saindo" pode indicar que não quer sair, ou que quer que você insista. "nem estou bebendo muito no momento" está correto, mas o entendimento sobre estar sem grana depende dessas pessoas conhecerem seus hábitos e situação financeira, obviamente.

Comment: então, qual é a diferença entre o frase com não e com nem?  Deu essa com o dinheiro só pra dar exemplo de uma outra razão, mas poderia ter sido qualquer coisa.  Ou os frases com nem são diferentes?  Ou não são.

Comment: 'nem' pode participar de muitas expressões, e neste link há várias delas. [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/pten/nem) Além de várias discussões sobre o assunto.

Comment: alguém faz favor pra mim e corrige a pergunta lá em cima?  Tentei escrever claro mas tô preocupado que talvez o razão que essas respostas não estão abordando a pergunta muito é que o questão tem muitos erros.  Sei falar bem melhor do que escrevo atualmente.

Comment: @AndréLyra (fale se não fala Inglês tá?) OK, so I'm going to speak in English in case there is a problem with communication here.  If I understand you correctly, you said earlier that the *nem* means a lack of interest or desire to go out.  However, in the example I gave with drinking, you seemed to indicate that it could be for any reason at all, so your first comment no longer seems to make much sense.  These points are not addressed in the link you gave.

Comment: Só em nota informativa, em português de Portugal usa-se também o nem, menos no último exemplo, que seria usado o não «não estou». Se eu ouvisse «nem estou» eu acharia que era um Brasileiro a falar.

Answer (score 6):

> Is the use of "nem" instead of "não" in the 2 examples above a regional thing or a "standard BP" thing?

**Nem** uma coisa, **nem** outra :) I mean, it's a slang word, and I am not sure it's purely based on region. I hear that frequently in São Paulo too, and there's at least an age factor also involved.

> Are there any dialects where "nem" is used almost completely interchangeably with "não", (or at least much more commonly than in standard Portuguese), and does this apply to Minas Gerais?

Yes, but I wouldn't say "dialects", because, technically, BP doesn't have dialects. I'm not sure about Minas Gerais, as I already mentioned it's not uncommon in SP either.

> Does the "nem" in these phrases hold any additional meaning than a simple "não" would? If so, what are the distinctions?

Yes, it does. To me it sounds like an emphasis, a more definite "não". But the exact meaning will depend on the context. Let's take your examples:

> "tô bem ocupado aqui, não tenho muito tempo pra sair."
>   "nem tô saindo muito também."

Here, *nem* and *também* are both adding emphasis to the answer as a whole, establishing more empathy between the speakers, like in "yeah, I'm on the same boat".

> "oi tudo bem, tá ocupado agora?"
>   "nem tô, vamo conversar"

Here the emphasis is more focused on the "no" part of the answer. It's similar to answering "no" versus "no, not at all". The latter is more emphatic.

Comment: Tu dizes que nem e também adicionam o ênfase de empatia entre os interlocutores, mas eu acho que será só o também. Se usares não em vez do nem, que é o caso do pt-PT, acho que fica com a mesma "empatia".

Comment: Obrigado muito pela resposta.  When you say "technically, BP doesn't have dialects."  I think you're mistaken. If you disagree with me, I would love to discuss it, but this is a whole other topic probably best kept separate from this question.

Comment: @Some_Guy you can use PL chat to discuss that: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio

Comment: Eu estou com o @Some_Guy : tecnicamente o Brazil tem dialetos; até Portugal, muito mais pequeno, os tem. Nós, os leigos, é que quando ouvimos falar em dialetos, tendemos a pensar em coisas como os dialetos do alemão e italiano, em que pessoas de dialetos diferentes poderão até ter dificuldade em se entender. Mas o linguistas classificam os vários falares regionais de Portugal e Brasil, que diferem em pouco mais que o sotaque, como dialetos. Vejam por exemplo [*dialeto* no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/dialeto).

Comment: @Jacinto - isso depende do linguista. A tradição alemã é considerar "dialetos" apenas línguas diferentes que fazem parte do mesmo espaço sócio-linguístico. Já os linguistas americanos acham que há um dialeto do Brooklin por oposição a um dialeto de Manhattan. Na tradição alemã, que me parece ser seguida pela maior parte dos linguistas brasileiros, isso são falares distintos, ou variantes, mas não dialetos.

Comment: Eu concordo que o uso de **nem** nos casos supracitados não passa de gíria e acredito que uma gíria relativamente recente. Já a ouvi principalmente em SP e RJ. Tem casos em que acredito que o **nem** é usado certinho como em "Nem sei o que dizer...". Já o **Num** já seria um sotaque. Bem comum em algumas regiões do interior do Brasil

Answer (score 2):

Registro aqui a experiência de um carioca que conhece apenas metade deste país enorme. Faço uma avaliação de cada exemplo separadamente:

> - "tô bem ocupado aqui, não tenho muito tempo pra sair"
> - "nem tô saindo muito também".

A primeira frase, aceitável apenas em português falado, e na informalidade, tem o "nem" implícito. Na verdade ela significa "Estou tão ocupado que nem tenho tempo para sair." (So busy have I been that I...)
A segunda frase é perfeitamente comum em pt-BR falado e informal, em qualquer estado do sul/sudeste. Em situações formais ou em pt-BR escrito, teria que ser "Eu não estou saindo muito também."  Neste caso não se trata de gíria, é apenas a linguagem coloquial. Nesse teu exemplo, mesmo em conversa informal, o "nem" é bem compreendido mas seria mais adequado o uso do "não".

> - "oi tudo bem, tá ocupado agora?"
> - "nem tô, vamo conversar"

Este segundo exemplo é bem mais informal, gramaticalmente incorreto e muitas vezes assim reconhecido por quem fala, mas não se importa com o fato. Aqui, "nem tô" já tem cheiro de gíria. Eu não diria que é um linguajar típico de Minas Gerais. Percebe-se com mais frequência nas camadas menos instruídas da população, e entre jovens com menos de 20 anos de idade, de qualquer grau de instrução, das grandes cidades da região sudeste (Rio de Janeiro, São Paulo, Belo Horizonte, etc). Em conversa com desconhecidos, em ambientes formais e em português escrito, deve sempre ser: "Bom dia (ou mesmo "oi"), tudo bem? (o senhor) está ocupado agora?", "Nâo, não estou. Vamos conversar."

Um outro uso comum da palavra "nem" seria na expressão "nem tô aí", "não tô nem aí pra isso", "não tô nem aí pra ela", gíria tipicamente brasileira e que significa: "não estou ligando", "não estou dando a mínima", "estou cagando e andando pra ela." Este último exemplo já bem mais vulgar.

> - Também, conheci umas paulistas velhinhas que falam "num" para não

A negativa "não" é muitas vezes pronunciada "num" quando seguida de outra palavra, principalmente na região sudeste: "num sei", "num estava lá", "num faça isso", mas sempre como uma vogal átona.  Isoladamente, o "não" soa sempre como "não".

Quanto a dialetos, sim, vários linguistas consideram que tenhamos muitos dialetos em pt-BR mas o uso de "nem" nos teus exemplos são mais um fenômeno de linguagem informal, relaxada, e gíria.  Para "dialetos do portuguès brasileiro" leia em: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro#Dialetos_do_portugu.C3.AAs_brasileiro

Comment: "nem tô aí pra isso" quer dizer o que?  Já ouvi falar disso, mas não sei se entendi direto.

Comment: @Some_Guy   "não tô nem aí pra isso" = "I couldn't care less".

Answer (score 1):

Acho que não é algo regional, pois já ouvi (e às vezes falo) isso aqui no Paraná (e como outros falaram nas respostas, parece ser comum em São Paulo).
Acredito que seja mais o caso de uma gíria. Como "nem" e "não" tem significados parecidos, as pessoas possam ter começado a usar um pelo outro.
Note que, embora seja possível trocar "não" por "nem", o contrário nem sempre é possível: "nem" originalmente é usado com os sentidos de "neither one, nor the other" ("nem um, nem outro), "me neither" ("nem eu") ou "not even".

I don't think it's something regional, because I've heard (and sometimes I speak) that here in Paraná, and just like some other people mentioned in  their answers, people speak like that in São Paulo as well.
I believe it's more like a slang. Since "nem" and "não" have similar meaning, people maybe started to use one for the other.
However, while it's possible to use "nem" for "não", the other way is not always possible, as " nem" originally means "neither... nor", "me neither" and "not even".

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, Brazilian Portuguese doesn't "have" actual dialects, or more properly speaking, there are no dialects originated from Portuguese in Brazil. That said, yes, there is some regional quality in the use of "nem" you report, and there is some association of it with Minas Gerais. More on that, later.

But the use of "nem" as interchangeable with "não" is context dependent in all of Brazil. Not even in Minas Gerais "não" can be replaced by "nem" regardless of context. And in no place in Brazil it is the case that "nem" is exclusively used as a "nem... nem..." conjunction similar to English "neither... nor...". A quite typical and widespread of "nem" is like this:

> - Você comeu minhas bolachinhas recheadas de chocolate?
> - Eu nem gosto de chocolate.

In that context, it translates into English rather as "not even" than as neither.

This seems to originate from "nem mesmo", with the ellision of the adverb:

> Nem mesmo estou saindo de casa, de tão doente que estou.
>
> Nem estou saindo de casa, de tão doente que estou.

This is probably the cause of the regional association with Minas Gerais, due to the amount of ellisions that characterise the speech of that region. Famously, *mineiros* would say *quencossô, oncotô, proncovô* instead of *quem que eu sou, onde que eu estou, para onde que eu vou*. But their informal speech is full not only of phonetic ellisions, but also morphological and sintactic ellisions. The ellision of "mesmo" in the expression "nem mesmo" may consequently more common, and extend to more contexts, in Minas than in the rest of Brazil.

A different ellision seems to me to be the explanation of

> "tô bem ocupado aqui, não tenho muito tempo pra sair"
>
> "nem tô saindo muito também".

I would say that this is a reduction from

> nem eu estou saindo muito também.

Ie, what is meant is, "nem você tem tido tempo para sair, nem eu tenho saído muito também", where you can see the more formal conjunction "nem... nem..."

Now this,

> "oi tudo bem, tá ocupado agora?"
>
> "nem tô, vamo conversar"

Seems more likely to be a *mineiro* idiom. It seems to imply that the asker is also not busy, or to be a kind of concessive conjunction, perhaps again an adverbial ellision from "nem tanto" ("not that much").

On the other hand, "não" cannot be replaced by "nem", not even in informal contexts, when in post verbal positions:

> Não quero não, obrigado. - but,
>
> *Nem quero nem, obrigado.

Also, stylistically, "nem" is much less forceful than "não" (this indeed may be a reason to use it, as a kind of euphemic expression), so someone under real stress would not say "nem consigo" instead of "não consigo". Perhaps related to this, "nem" is not used as an interjection.

So, to address your questions, in some contexts this can be standard BP (as in instead of "nem mesmo"), in others it is more likely colloquial (as in instead of "nem eu"), in further others (as in instead of "nem tanto") it sounds more like popular Portuguese, and in many other contexts it would not be acceptable for most speakers (such as an interjection, as in post-verbal positions, or as in politeness formulas).

And while there is some regional aspect in these variations, and the Minas Gerais factor is real, neither there is any part of Brazil where "nem" can never be used in any context where "não" would be the choice word, nor there is any part of the country where "nem" can be used instead of "não" regardless of context.

Finally, as I hope to have demonstrated, "nem" can perform many other functions more than "either... nor". It is rarely a full replacemen for "não", and, when it is, it is stylistically different, carrying a weaker connotation than the classic verbal negation.

Comment: I *love* the "nem quero nem example".  That sticks out as obviously unnatural to me too.  Now I think of it, it seems obvious that it isn't a straight substitution for não... By the way, when I talk about dialectical differences, I mean in the sense of dialects described here https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro#Dialetos_do_portugu.C3.AAs_brasileiro), tem nada a ver com raízes dos dialetos do portugal, é que o brasil mesmo tem muitos variações na sua linguagem que evoluiu independentemente nos ultimos 500 anos então é justo chamar-lo "dialetos".

Comment: I still have a couple of questions about those cases where it nem is used. "Nem mesmo estou saindo de casa" is something like "I'm not even going out of the house" right?  The last example where you said "It seems to imply that the asker is also not busy, or to be a kind of concessive conjunction." I think is not right. I'm pretty sure I've heard "nem" used to emphatically disagree with something.  Like "tâ me zooando..." "nem tô!".

Comment: Maybe it's something like the UK London youth slang "I ain't even doing that though" usage haha

Answer (score 0):

Eu creio que você compreendeu o uso mais comum da palavra "nem" que é uma conjunção com uso semelhante ao inglês "neither" ou "nor" que tem o objetivo de negar mais de uma coisa, inclusive, "nem" pode substituir as duas palavras em uma mesma frase.

> English: By the way, neither Alex nor I drink.
>
> Português: A propósito, nem Alex nem eu bebemos.

Como você pode ver, "nem" substitui adequadamente as duas palavras em inglês.

O outro uso que você também notou é a palavra "nem" indicando a recusa a algo ou negando uma situação. Esse uso também, é bastante comum. Veja os exemplos:

> Nem me fale uma coisa dessas.
>
> Esse valor não dá pra pagar nem a roda desse carro.

Sobre ser ou não regionalismo, não posso garantir para qualquer ocasião, mas no Brasil eu posso afirmar que pessoas de diferentes regiões vão te compreender sem nenhum problema.

Veja algumas informações gramaticais nesse [link](https://www.dicio.com.br/nem/).

Comment: "B - Eu também não./Eu também não gosto." é que é substituível por "Nem eu".

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas eu tô perguntando sobre a linguá falado.  Por exemplo, tu falou que pareça certo usar nem no seu segundo exemplo mas não é, mas sei que aqui seria bem normal falar "nem eu" nesse situação.  Isso é um dessas coisas que são "erradas" mas que tudo mundo fala informalmente? Caso sim, é bom saber isso, mas vai me confundir se omitir usos que eu ouço todo dia quando tá descrevendo como usa e como não usa palavras XD

Comment: @AndréLyra isso

Comment: E o questão é se estes exemplos que eu dei na pergunta são coisas regionais (fora da norma padrão) ou não, (e caso não, por favor explique a regra que aplica).  Talvez isso não foi claro, vou tentar melhorar a pergunta um pouco.

Comment: "Esse valor não dá pra pagar nem a roda desse carro." neste caso está subentendido "Esse valor não dá para pagar nem sequer a roda desse carro" ou "Esse valor não dá para pagar nem ao menos a roda desse carro"

Comment: @James Na segunda frase, por que não "Nem eu"?

Comment: @BrunoLopes na verdade, foi puramente esquecimento. quando escrevi parecia que não era uma opção, vou corrigir minha resposta.

Comment: @James a sua resposta esta meia confusa, "me neither" é "nem eu" e não "eu nem".

Comment: @JorgeB. De fato, eu não tinha entendido bem a pergunta do OP e estava tentando exemplificar alguns usos de "nem", mas não era isso que ele estava precisando saber. Eu exclui a parte que tinha ficado confusa.